# Kerberos authentication, service host and access to KDC

Tags: active-directory, firewall, kerberos, springframework

I have a web application (hostname: service.domain.com) and I wish to use Kerberos authentication to identify users that are logged into a Windows domain. Microsoft AD (Windows Server 2008 R2) is providing the Kerberos service.

The service is a Java web application using Spring Security Kerberos extension library to implement SPNEGO/Kerberos protocol. I have created a keytab file in AD that contains a shared secret that should be enough to authenticate Kerberos tickets that are sent by the client browsers using the web application.

My question is, is service host (service.domain.com) required to have firewall access (TCP/UDP 88) to KDC (kdc.domain.com) or is the keytab file enough for the service host to be able to decrypt the Kerberos tickets and provide authentication?

Comment: The service does not need access to the KDC in your setup. The clients absolutely do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **service** never needs to talk to the **KDC**. It needs a **keytab** generated by the **KDC**, but that you can copy over any way you want. They never have to talk to each other.

An overly simplified version of what I believe goes on goes more or less like this:

### Setting up the service

- **KDC** generates a service **keytab** (which is something like a secret key/password if you like)
- this **keytab** is provided to the **service** some way (`scp` or carried on a USB stick if you want)

### Client connecting to the service

- **client** requests a service **ticket** from the **KDC**
- **KDC** generates a service **ticket**, which contains some information that can only be decrypted by the service **keytab** (this is the file that sits on your server)
- **client** sends its service **ticket** to the **service**
- the **service** uses its **keytab** to verify the **ticket** (no network communication necessary)

Comment: Thank you, this is how I understood it too from the Kerberos Wikipedia article. This question seems to have contradictory answer: [Kerberos Authentication for Webservers](http://serverfault.com/questions/188316/kerberos-authentication-for-webservers)

Comment: Well, I don't know what happened in that other answer, but I do have a very remote SSH server doing Kerberos based authentication, and it certainly has no access to the KDC that is on my private LAN at home. Could there be something odd going on with webservers? Maybe, but I highly doubt it.