# Which servers to copy keytab file to

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, kerberos, single-sign-on, mitkerberos

I am trying to setup a simple Kerberos environment in which a client server authenticates to a webservice (in my case OpenSSH) via a Kerberos server.

I generated a keytab file on the KDC but am not quite sure which servers to copy the file to. Do I only need to copy it to the machine that is offering the service or also to the client machine that wants to authenticate to the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a normal situation, the keytab file you created (usually, using a service account principal (or instance), for example ssh/hostname) **should be placed on the "client"** of that kerberos service.

and on this client, **you will use this keytab (caching the account credentials) to authenticate your service against the KDC**, with a command like this one (in the case of a service, this is usually done by the service, in its code or via a script, at boot time) :

```
kinit -kt /path/to/keytab.file principal/name
```

keytabs somehow contain your account (or service account) credentials (e.g principal & password) so that you don't have to authenticate manually but you can do it automatically using this keytab (and the keytab should have strict permissions,naturly)

hope that helps

note : the KDC also uses keytabs, be careful not to upload this keytab to your client! it contains KDC/kadmin information !

to be sure that you are using the right one, you can connect to your KDC from the client using kadmin and create the keytab from there, for example:

```
client$ kadmin -p your_admin_login/admin  # login to the KDC
client$ kadmin> ktadd -kt /path/to/keytab.keytab <principal_name>  # generate a keytab locally for account principal_name
client$ kadmin> exit
client$ kinit -kt /path/to/keytab.keytab <principal_name> # test it
client$ <configure the keytab path in your app>
```

regards,

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just to be absolutely clear, by **client** do you mean the server on which the service is running or the server that authenticates to the service? I'm a bit confused with the terminology since sometimes all servers besides the KDC are called "clients" whereas the KDC is referred to as the **server**.

Comment: the server on which the service is running. as long as the service is "kerberized", it means that this service (when starting) should authenticate against the KDC

Comment: So accepted answer in https://serverfault.com/questions/454138/kerberos-authentication-service-host-and-access-to-kdc?rq=1 is wrong when it says "The service never needs to talk to the KDC"??? Thanks!